# Why does the stability of a nucleus depend on the binding energy $\textit{per nucleon}$ instead of the total binding energy?

Tags: nuclear-physics, stability, binding-energy

The larger the total binding energy of a nucleus, the greater the minimum energy that must be added to infinitely separate the constituent nucleons. Shouldn't the total binding energy, then, be used to determine the stability of a nucleus? I don't understand why the binding energy per nucleon is used instead.

Comment: Because in a system of $n$ nucleons you look for combinations of nucleons that have the highest binding energy taken all together. It is not a one-body problem, it is an $n$-body problem.

Answer (score 0):

Jon Custer is right, here is why.

The *total* binding energy is the sum of the energy in the *attractive* part due to the residual nuclear force between quarks in neighboring nucleons and the *repulsive* part due to the proton-proton electrostatic repulsion.

The attractive part is strictly local, acting to stick protons and neutrons together that are close enough to touch- it is a very short-ranged force. On the other hand, a single proton in the nucleus feels the repulsion of *all* the other protons in the nucleus, not just its nearest neighbors. Once the net attractive contribution becomes equal to the repulsive contribution, the binding energy *per nucleon* approaches zero and there's almost nothing left to make it energetically favorable for the nucleus to remain in one piece: give it just the right bump, and it flies apart.

This is why the binding energy per nucleon is so strong in helium and relatively much weaker in uranium.