# How does the increased binding energy per nucleon help in stability?

Tags: nuclear-physics, coulombs-law, stability, binding-energy, elements

I have some read answers on this forum, some books like Halliday Resnick and my course books. I have understood that binding energy is the energy we need to supply to break nucleus into individual nucleons (or the opposite). What I can not understand is why a high binding energy or more released energy helps in stability. **Does it somehow offset coulombic repulsion?** or should I just take it as a generalisation as in chemistry that an exothermic reaction is more stable?

*One more thing, we have been told in class about some theory where neutron and proton convert into each other to gain stability but only in short.*

Comment: "What I can not understand is why a high binding energy or more released energy helps in stability." - check your previous sentence: the higher the binding energy, the more energy you need to supply (and hence harder) in order to separate the nucleus. Also check [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/706963/222555), and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/595714/222555) and related links.

Comment: @Vangi Can you please suggest me a good book on nuclear physics, I have a lot of doubts.The answers are on the internet but too hard to find the right ones.

Comment: I am not very familiar with this subject, so I can not give you a well informed list. The only book I have used is B.R. Martin, Nuclear and Particle Physics, but I don't know how it is compared to other books. There probably are better suggestions on the internet.